# Ubuntu,browser can surf the internet, but I cannot ping

Tags: firefox, ping

I am using ubuntu.I can use firefox in it to surf the internet properly,like google and any other websites.But I cannot use ping command .For example ,when I "ping www.google.com.hk", it get no response.[image]
When I ping ip directly,result is the same.

my ifconfig output is:

[image]

my ufw is inactive.

Anyone can tell me the problem?

Comment: Well I can successfully ping you, so at least there's that.  Could this be something to do with you using a Chinese ISP?

Answer (score 2):

Pinging an IP address is done using a protocol called ICMP on top of IP.

One of the main purpose of this protocol is to provide network administrator with information on the network like "is this host alive", "how many times need a packet to travel to this host", "how many hops to cross to reach this host", ...

As such, this protocol can give valuable information to potential attacker so it is often denied by the firewalls protecting a given host or network of hosts.

Beeing unable to reach a host by ping doesn't means that this host is not reachable at all. It just means that ICMP is blocked somewhere.

As you say that you are able to resolve DNS names and surf the web, I don't see a problem in this.
There is just somewhere between you and the host(s) a firewall blocking your ping.

And having the ICMP (pings) blocked, doesn't mean at all that you are limited into your Internet access (which is usually done on TCP port 80 and 443).